# Gemfile.lock missing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Okay I have been stuck for hours now. When I try to push to heroku it says:

Gemfile.lock is required. Please run "bundle install" locally
 !     and commit your Gemfile.lock.

So I see I need a Gemfile.lock which I do not have and when I run "bundle install" it says:

Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.

Then I run "bundle show" and get:

Could not find gem 'sqlite3 (= 2.8.17)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.

any clues?

Comment: Provide info about OS you are using. Ruby/Rails versions? Also, post the error you get.

Answer (score 0):

Can you create your rails project again?

It sounds like you are missing a bunch of files you need.  If you aren't too far through developing, create a new project and copy the code you have into it.

Comment: I was not using bundle exec when using bundle install and had mutiple versions of rails installed, complete beginner mistake. thanks for your responses